# TLF TextField lose focus, when clearing content

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have following problem.

I try to achive a simple placeholder-function with Actionscript3.

First i tried to use an Input-TextField, but there i had the problem that i couldn´t type in Numbers.. only letters.. so i am using an TLF Textfield now.

The placeholder-function itself works fine with this code.. where "plz" is the instance property name

```
    plz.addEventListener( 

     FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, 

      function(event: FocusEvent) : void { 

        if(plz.text == "Ihre Postleitzahl"){
            plz.text = "";
        }       
     } 
);
```

but when i do like so the TextField is loosing its focus.. so the user would have to click again to start typing.

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after clearing your text (stage class):

```
stage.focus = plz;
```

Comment: i used this line but didn´t worked as well... for me i don´t need it anymore... i used a second textfield and remove that one.. thx